# Multilanguage website in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, localization

Me and my friend are going to build a multilanguage website and we were discussing
what the best way is to support the multiple languages.

My opinion was to use PO files to easily edit the language files.
But my friend wants to use te resource files in visual studio.

So I want to ask, what's the best way ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid ways to do it.

If you are going to be using GTK# as your widget set, then PO files are a good way forward.

If you are going to be using Winforms/WPF/Webforms/MVC, then resource files/satellite assemblies files are a good way forward. Additionally, if you are using visual studio it has great support for this kind of localization.

Comment: Why would they be using Winforms to build a website?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what a PO file is.

However, .Net has pretty good built in support for multilingual resource files.  I'd go that route.

Comment: PO files are used for localization of GTK applications.